# Get user browser, os, flash version, javascript info

Tags: flash, operating-system

I came across a website recently that outputs a whole bunch of user info: IP, browser, OS, flash version, javascript, etc in a very easy to use format.

It was specifically designed for remote support, in order to determine user operating environment.

However, I cant recall the name of the website....any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try http://supportdetails.com/